# Windows 10 - Can't access recovery menu "advanced options"

Tags: windows, boot, recovery

[Edited]

I am having trouble accessing the windows 10 "Advanced Options" menu in the recovery menu.

I tried using `shutdown /r /o /t 0` but only got a limited recovery screen.

I also tried tricking windows into booting straight into recovery by force-killing the system as windows booted, 3 times in a row. I got something to happen, but that something was just a screen telling me to press F1 to enter the recovery menu.

Upon pressing F1 the system rebooted again, into the same exact menu. I tried a couple more times, but each time it just said "F1 to access recovery menu." So that's not going to work, apparently.

Comment: "Extract contents of ISO to a portable SSD USB drive (functionally the same as a normal flash drive)" - This does not make the portable SSD USB drive bootable.  Why are you not using a tool like Rufus to make your installation disk? Make sure you do NOT make the media support UEFI, since your current installation, is on an MBR partition.  Windows environment will not see the disk if you do.

Comment: that's a great question but it doesn't help me with my main goal of accessing the recovery command prompt.

Comment: I know it's a great question.  The answer to that question, and please do take the suggested steps, does not change the fact the information is required to answer your question.

Comment: forgive me, i did not see your edits.

Comment: in the past, when i did this with old computers, a simple restart and using the "trick windows" method would work just fine. i got into recovery menu and was able to do stuff. now it, for some reason it doesn't. the content of a random flash drive/ssd aren't going to change the methods. windows updates might. or maybe it's the fact that im on a dual boot.

Comment: Are you positive you even have a WinRE partition?  You should still make the installation environment with Rufus, make sure it supports MBR, and change the boot order in order to boot to that disk.  I thought the end goal was to install Windows?  The WinRE partition that is typically created cannot be used to install Windows anyway (you can Reset the installation).  You have to boot to the installation media to install Windows on a partition.

Comment: On my /dev/sda (main drive) there are 4 partitions. one 499MB called "Recovery Partition" one called "EFI something something", it's 99MB, one for windows, and one for Lubuntu

Comment: As for my old method... what I would do, is once I rebooted into recovery CMD, I'd launch notepad, then use the notepad file browse window to find the drive letter containing the ISO contents. then i'd simply right click and run the setup file. it covers up the screen (and the command prompt) and i can go through the menus, erase the old windows partition, and choose it for the installation. it always goes through the steps fine. the trouble this time, is getting to that point.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93209/discussion-between-harrison-smith-and-ramhound).